# Use API while charging via USB (Sony QX1)

Tags: camera, sony

is it possible to use the camera remote API while charging? I use a Sony QX1. It seems that the camera stops its WLAN connection when you plug in an USB cable even it is only connected with a power adapter. Is there a way to avoid the behaviour?

Best regards,
Oliver Bollmann

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about camera hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the cameras have an option which will change the USB behaviour. Allowing it to be on while charging.

Sony needs to make all these cameras have an 'always on' mode. As is, most have soft power which means any power outage and the camera will never turn back on without user intervention.